# Using Enum in VS2012 Express with EF5 and test Units

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, enums, ef-code-first

I'm having an issue with VS2012 express web

I use a VS2012 pro and my partner use a VS2012 express web.

We share the same project, using EF5 code first.

In a model description i use an enum.

On my computer with VS2012 Pro i had no problem to create a database in test units.
On the computer of my partner with VS2012 express web, VS returns an error, telling it can not handle the enum.

here is the error message (sorry it is in french)

*Message de résultat  :

La méthode d'initialisation prjAGE.Metier.Test.Tests.AnnuaireDesTiers.TU_RepositoryContact.MyTestInitialize a levé une exception. System.Data.MetadataException: System.Data.MetadataException: Le schéma spécifié n'est pas valide.
Erreurs :
Impossible de trouver un type de couche objet correspondant au type conceptuel 'AGE.Metier.DAL.EnumCivilite'.*

We already have checked that all updates have been done and the version of EF5 given by NuGet.

What have we missed ?

Jean-Baptiste

Comment: You could at least translate the exception message for us...

Comment: It could be translate as System.Data.MetadataException: System.Data.MetadataException schema not valid. Error Imposible to find a type --- of the conceptual type EnumCivilite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no problem caused by your Visual Studio version. However this issue seems very similar to the problem described here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ec37698d-a7ad-4a7d-873d-3ea61c917eed/ef-50-enum-schema-specified-is-not-valid-errors?forum=adodotnetentityframework

And there is an issue about enums that span assemblies: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/532

For further options check whether the web versions VS2012 express web works correctly if you change your EF project and Unit test project to EF 6 because this error might be caused by the limitations of what projects the VS2012 express can edit as EF 5 still uses the System.Data.Entity dll while in the EF 6 only the whole code base was moved to the EntityFramework.dll (while the namespace for those classes are still System.Data.Entity of course)

Comment: Ok, it is exactly the issue we have. we will upgrade our project to EF6 next week. thanks a lot.